# Mysql multiple distinct wont work

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have tried this multiple distinct from MySQL and I cant seem to get anything to work... I have a table that is a history table. The appartments can be found many times from the same building with different status. I need to find the newest one for each appartment (the one with the highest id ORDER BY id)

```
id   building appartment_id status
208  1        2             2  
209  1        3             2   
210  1        4             2   
211  1        5             2  
212  1        6             2  
213  1        7             2  
214  1        2             1  
215  1        2             3
```

But how do I do that?! :S
I have tried this:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(appartment_id, building) 
    FROM `ib30_history` 
    group by appartment_id, building 
    order by id DESC
```

It seems to work but im not sure that is the right way of doing it and the code that uses the output seems to make funny things running through the data so im not sure it really works!

Comment: @MarcB: Why have you removed what OP has tried so far?

Comment: @firee: odd, didn't do that on purpose. I've reverted/re-editted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of distinct and use something like:

GROUP BY building , appartment_id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT yourtable.id, yourtable.building, yourtable.appartment_id, yourtable.status
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY building, appartment_id
) AS child ON yourtable.id = child.id
```

Comment: +1. But `building, appartment_id` do not have  to be in derived `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called `GROUP BY`, and MySQL's documentation knows a lot about how it's to be used. At the timeI type this, the OP doesn't contain a query so I cannot give you an example...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table_name a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(id) as max_id
 FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY appartment_id) b
ON (b.max_id = a.id)
```